# XSLT - Remove certain strings from the text node

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'have xml like follows,

```
<doc>
<p type="para">.<t/>JMS<s/>
    <style type="italic">Bambulla</style>
    <s/>2012-13, s. 65 (ad § 3)
</p>
</doc>
```

what I need is remove `.` that places right after  `<p type="para">`. note that every time `.` places between `<p type="para">` and `<t/>`.

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="p[@type='para']">
        <p type="para">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>
```

How can I expand above xsl to remove only that `.` string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `<xsl:template match="p[@type='para']/node()[1][self::text() and . = '.' and following-sibling::node()[1][self::t[not(node())]]]"/>` then any first child node of a `p[@type='para']` which is a text node with string value `.` and is followed by an empty `t` element would be deleted.